# Error Converting Word Document to PDF in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to covert Microsoft Word and Excel documents to PDF in my application. I know there are tools that will make it easier, but we cannot purchase them so am trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop. I added through NuGet Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 15.0.4795.1001 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1001. My code is:

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

    [HttpPost("getsupportingfilepdf")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SupportFileResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public ActionResult GetSupportingFilePDF()
    {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            if (appWord.Documents != null)
            {
                //yourDoc is your word document
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(@"C:\workspace\DatabaseSRS.docx");
                string pdfDocName = @"C:\workspace\DatabaseSRS.pdf";
                if (wordDocument != null)
                {
                    wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfDocName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
                    wordDocument.Close();
                }
                appWord.Quit();
            }
```

When I try to run it, I get:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

I have tried removing and re adding the NuGet packages, but it is still happening. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Edit: I have Microsoft Office 365 installed on my machine.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Word installed on the computer?

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop` is a package that makes use of installed Microsoft Office products, as such you need the appropriate MS Office applications installed.

Comment: I have Microsoft Office 365 installed

Comment: Office 365 is not the same as desktop Office, so the office interop won't work.  There are some projects like OpenXML (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-sheets) that you could use.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2)

Comment: The following may be helpful if you decide to use NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617565/vb-dot-net-mail-merge-word-document-without-ms-office-installed). You'll find that using the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools) is helpful. Also see [DocumentFormat.OpenXml Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1).

Comment: I did look at OpenXML as I am using it to parse Excel files and it looks like it doesn't support saving as a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue as well. Where I was using the wrong office version and installed the library office version. after installing the correct version which matches the library and MS office it worked for me.

Your machine needs Office installed. **Version 15.0.0.0** of the library should correspond to **Office 2013** - which needs to be installed on your machine other versions of Office will not work. Try installing the relevant office version and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Microsoft Word (office) [installed](https://www.stefanfeenstra.nl/sharepoint-2013/converting-office-documents-pdf-office-interop-assemblies/#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Office%20needs%20to%20be%20installed).